# TComponet / any other Superclass and its child item detection

Tags: delphi, controls, parent, menuitem, sender

I have Popup menu control on form ( grr, I most likely gonna make it dynamic - hate static tools ). It has got Item with SubMenu. SubMenu has three Menu Items ( TMenuItem class ).

I need to check by taking Sender param in if..then statement whenever procedure has been called by the Item with SubMenu or by SubMenu Items.

I tried different vraiations with typecasting and superclass operations but no luck. I think it is possible to something like this:

```
if FindControl(MenuItemWithSubMenu.Handle) = TControl(Sender as TComponent).Parent then ...
```

but, of course, with correct typecasting and commands ..

Any ideas appreciated.

**Additional Information by community request:**

The code itsef ( if I simply check by component name prop ) looks like this:

```
procedure TForm1.xClick(Sender: TObject); // procedure that has attached onClick from    PopupActionBar1 Items
begin    
if ((TComponent(Sender).Name = 'Unloadresources1') or  // PopupActionBar1.Items[3]
     (TComponent(Sender).Name = 'VKPCache11')       or // PopupActionBar1.Items[3].Items[0]
     (TComponent(Sender).Name = 'VKPCache21')       or // PopupActionBar1.Items[3].Items[1]
     (TComponent(Sender).Name = 'AllCache31')       or // PopupActionBar1.Items[3].Items[2]
     (ActLoadVal = 2)) and (PopupActionBar1.Items[3].Caption = 'Delete VKP Cache') then begin .. end;
end;
```

The problem is that it is way to weak approach and needs additional coding if programm user wants to add / drag'n'drop / insert component or control or object in runetime. In this way programm itself would automatically do hald job in my place - know what to call and when :)

On ( static ) Form1 is ( static ) PopupActionBar1. It has four Items. Forth Item has SubMenu - with three Items.

Both fourth item with submenu items ( PopupActionBar1.Items[3] ) and three submenu items ( PopupActionBar1.Items[3].Items[0 .. 2] OnClick event handlers are set to Procedure containing If..Then statement wrote above.

Task - by eveluating Sender parameter and using its OOP capabilities - check if Procedure has been called from PopupActionBar1.Items[3] Menu Item or its SubMenu items ( PopupActionBar1.Items[3].Items[0] or PopupActionBar1.Items[3].Items[1] or PopupActionBar1.Items[3].Items[2] ).

I have tried various syntax ... also tried typecasting manipulations with TControl, TWinControl, TComponent .. ( no use of TObject is it has got no Parent ( excl. OLE ) ..

Comment: In which event does your code reside? Also I'm unsure what you are trying to achieve. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: In what manner? Code snipp? Diagram?

Comment: Please add more elaborate code, as your question seems (based on the discussion under Sertac's answer) much more complex than it is formulated now.

Comment: Roger that! More info needed?

Comment: Not providing an answer in fear of misunderstanding <g>, but you really should not attach a handler to "UnloadResources1" (unless you plan to modify subitems on the fly), the handler will fire when the submenu is shown and then fire again when the user makes a selection. Other than that I'd go "if (Sender is TMenuItem) and (TMenuItem(Sender).Parent = UnloadResources1) then".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to find the Item, it is already the Sender. I.e. you can do

```
procedure TForm1.MyItem1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if Sender = MyItem1 then
    [...]
  else if Sender = MyItem2 then
```

I generally use the tag property to differentiate the MenuItem that triggered the handler. Not elegant, but works.

```
procedure TForm1.Item1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  case TMenuItem(Sender).Tag of
    0: [..];
    1: [..];
    [..]
```

One has to remember to set the all menu item's OnClick events to point to the same handler. This is something I don't remember till I see clicking one has no effect..

Comment: yes, I know - it is super-easiest approach and provides static detection and thus - Application does not have assigning and sender dynamics. Here are situations
- user adds new item by Drag and Drop,
- by WMs ( hackers , etc. ),
or any other way I have not handled or simply cannot know it characteristics without advanced Mouse and VCLs WM Processing but what ANYWAY has to be handled by one procedure. That is reason why I need to detect them as decedents / children of the parent TMenuItem. Thanks for tag idea, but it is just other way and only real difference is that Tag is public Property :)

Comment: @HX_unbanned: I still don't get it.
It would be meaningful, for instance, if you handled the clicks in a WM_COMMAND handler you could find an item by "MyItem := PopupMenu1.FindItem(Message.ItemID, fkCommand);".
But if you're in an OnClick handler however, the "Sender" *is* your Item.

Comment: yes, it is my item. So - I check if this Item ( =Sender ) is Item with SubMenus or the Item is inside the SubMenu :)

if..then statement in the lame and basic ( non-dynamic ) approach looks like this:

if (TComponent(Sender).Name = 'MenuWithSubMenus') or (TComponent(Sender).Name = 'MenuWithSubMenus_SubMenu1') or TComponent(Sender).Name = 'MenuWithSubMenus_SubMenu2' ) ...
then ...

But If I check that Sender is MenuWithSubMenus or it is any SubMenu of MenuWithSubMenus, I can get automatic Attaching to necessarry things just by assigning OnClick event in Design-Time or Run-Time.
Is it clear now?

Comment: Not quite. :-( If nothing comes up in a while perhaps you'd edit the question to include a broader aspect of your code, and answer Uwe's question (in which event..).

Comment: More descriptive comment added in main question :)